# Word 2007 VBA macro to remove paragraph marks from inside multiple hyperlinks (display text)

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros, hyperlink

Does anyone have a macro which will remove para marks, ONLY from inside all my hyperlinks (not from normal text outside the hyperlinks)?

This is a common problem copying text from many web sites into MS Word (but many others don't do this!).

[image: orig web page-hyperlink 2 lines]

[image: copied into word-5 lines]

[image: code in word-NO para marks]

[image: edit hyperlink box-can't edit display text]

Comment: Do you need a macro?  Couldn't you just do a find and replace for ^p where font color is blue (0,0,255), replacing with nothing?  That would get rid of the blank paragraph marks but keep the soft returns within the  hyperlinks.

Comment: Tanya thanks will try that!  My hyperlinks are styles which may vary within a document thanks to Office creating new styles when you import from other documents and no ability to amalgamate them that I have found - macro would overcome checking whether any hyperlinks have different styles...

Comment: Great that you solved this and posted the solution.  Rather than using the SOLVED tag in the title, the convention is to accept your own answer.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks have done.  The title change is to show hapless google searchers like me that this actually IS solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tanya who provided the clue-

```
Sub D___Hyperlinks_ParaMarksReplWithSpaces()

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Hyperlink")
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .text = "^p"
    .Replacement.text = " "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

With Selection.Find
    .text = "^l"
    .Replacement.text = " "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```